# Is there a way to make the html elements of a website more visible?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

While scraping the following website (https://www.middletownk12.org/Page/4113), this code could not locate the table rows (To get the staff name, email & department) even though they are visible when I use the Chrome developer tools. The soup object is not readbale enough to locate the tr tags that have the info needed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.middletownk12.org/Page/4113"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print(response.text)
```

I used different libraries such as bs4, request & selenium with no chance. I also tried Css selectors & XPATH with selenium with no chance. The Tr elements could not be located.

Comment: That table of contact information is filled in by Javascript *after* the page has loaded. The content doesn't exist in the page's HTML and you won't see it using `requests`. You will either need to (a) use an actual browser with Javascript support via tools like Playright or Selenium, or (b) examine the network log when loading the page and see if you can determine the request that populates that data (and then try fetching it yourself).

Comment: Try `print(soup.prettify())`

Comment: You may want to try the python selenium package to run through a browser so that you see the page after the javascript rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That table of contact information is filled in by Javascript after the page has loaded. The content doesn't exist in the page's HTML and you won't see it using requests.

By using the developer tools available in the browser, we can examine the requests made after the page has loaded. There are a lot of them, but at least in my browser it's obvious the contact information is loaded near the end.

Looking at the request log, I see a request for a spreadsheet from `docs.google.com`:

[image]

If we examine that entry, we find that it's a request for:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSPXpr9MjxZXaYteex9ZMydfXx81YWqf5Coh9TfcB0q8YNRWrYTAtypX3IPlW44ZzXmhaSiQGNY-yle/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0
```

And if we fetch the above link, we get a spreadsheet with the source data for that table.

---

> Actually I used Selenium & then bs4 without any results. The code does not find the 'tr' elements...

Why are you using Selenium? The whole point to this answer is that you don't need to use Selenium if you can figure out the link to retrieve the data -- which we have.

All we need is `requests` to fetch the data and `BeautifulSoup` to parse it:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSPXpr9MjxZXaYteex9ZMydfXx81YWqf5Coh9TfcB0q8YNRWrYTAtypX3IPlW44ZzXmhaSiQGNY-yle/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0'

res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
  print(f"{link.text}: {link.get('href')}")
```

Comment: Great! thanks a lot for the insight. I got that spreadsheet. Not sure if there is a way to scrape the email addresses from the website as they are visible of the GoggleSheet? Thanks

Comment: The email addresses appear to be available as the target (`href`) of links in that document. You should be able to process it using BeautifulSoup or another HTML parser.

Comment: Actually I used Selenium & then bs4 without any results. The code does not find the 'tr' elements :        First try :  contact = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{i}]')))
 ### Second way ####.  contact = driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#\30  > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i})')

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with Selenium, but I've updated the answer with an example that shows how to parse the data using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Your example is well appreciated. Since I am scraping a lot of similar websites and most of them list the data in several pages. I needed selenium to click on those page numbers to scrape the whole site. Thanks